# ObservableCollection dependency warning

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin

I have an `ObservableCollection` created in a PCL project that I'm accessing from a Xamarin.iOS project.

It works fine, but I get this warning when compiling for a device:

> Warning MT3005: The dependency 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' of the assembly 'Test.PCL, Version=1.0.4984.40730, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' was not found. Please review the project's references. (MT3005)

...and I just can't work out why. Both projects reference System.Windows.

The PCL is targeting .NET 4.5, Silverlight 5 and Xamarin.Android/iOS (profile 24). I'm using Xamarin alpha, Mono 3.2.2 on OS X.

Is it a Mono bug or something I can fix?

Comment: Why are you referencing System.Windows?  That's a very platform specific assembly, not something you would use in a PCL.

Comment: ObservableCollection lives in System.Windows, at least that's what Xamarin Studio tells me. Without it I get an error telling me to reference it.

Comment: in an iOS project, I have ObservableCollection in System.Collections.ObjectModel.

Comment: Hmm ok, this just seems really buggy (I guess it is alpha). When removing the references to System.Windows, the editor shows me an error: `error CS0103: The name ObservableCollection does not exist in the current context`. But it then compiles fine. Maybe I need to just wait a bit longer before trying to use PCLs!

Comment: ...at least it does in my simple test project. If I remove the reference to System.Windows in my real-world app project, it fails to compile: Error CS0012: The type `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1<T>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly `System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'